# Better interactive broadcasting using agora.io

Tags: python, agora.io

I made a web platform with flask for python, and is now hoping to integrate the Interactive Broadcasting abilities of Agora.io to allow users to create/join the broadcast service.

1) Is it possible to integrate the Agora.io SDK with flask web application?
2) Can i get a demo for it?

I have searched a lot and couldnt find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yeah, you can. As the Agora.io SDKs are big frontends, you do not have to add them directly into your flask backend. You should just interact with them through signals emitted from you flask server, manage channel names / user IDs in your flask server.

2) Most of Agora.io SDKs can be found [here/Agoraio](https://github.com/Agoraio) and [here/Agoraio-Community](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community). Be aware that most of them are about frontends.

*Here by `frontend`, I mean web, desktops, and mobile apps.*